# How to click on the checkbox when another element receives the click action?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with click action in Selenium Python. 
I try to click on the checkbox, but  element receive this click. 
I tried to resolve this problem by correctly choice of this element, I checked CSS SELECTOR, XPATHs and iteration by elements which I found by CLASS NAME but even if I have an absolute path to the element, the  element where my  is nested catches the click action. 
I don't know how I can resolve this issue, many you have some ideas?

It's my HTML code with  element which I need to click:
[image]

And Selenium Exception:

`Message: unknown error: Element <span class="checkbox__replacer"></span> is not clickable at point (40, 178). Other element would receive the click: <label class="checkbox">...</label>\n`

And my selectors:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please use the xpath as below to select the checkbox.

```
//input[@id='vf-pp-accept-terms2']
```

Comment: Anytime my friend :)